# Blacklist all, then whitelist public files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know this could probably be solved in a second if I had access to server config, but unfortunately I don't, so I have to solve this with only .htaccess.

I'm building a site MVC-style, meaning I have my index.php in the root, models in a models-directory,  views in a views-directory, etc. The thing is, I have some folders that should be public, like css, javascript and images. As I'm quite forgetful, I prefer blacklisting everything, then whitelisting only the things I want to be public (I rather get an error the first time I try to access an image because I forgot to whitelist it, than forget to blacklist my config-directory and have all sorts of sensitive stuff be available).

My .htaccess-file in root currently looks like this:

```
<filesMatch "\..+$">
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<filesMatch "^index\.(htm|html|shtml|wml|pwml|php|php3|php4|php5)$">
    allow from all
</filesMatch>

<Files "tests.php">
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</files>
```

The issue I have is that I cannot figure out how to allow access to the subdirectories. Location and Directory seems to be what should be used, but for some reason these aren't allowed in .htaccess, only server config, and since I don't have access to it, it becomes problematic. Are there any other ways to solve this that I haven't thought of?

Comment: You could just create multiple htaccess files and place them in the appropriate folder.

Comment: Preferably, I would have wanted to keep everything in a single file, but it seems it's not possible, so I went with the multiple files-solution in the end.